# Presenting code on my personal website

Tags: svn

I would like to develop a portfolio of code for prospective employers to browse through. The interface used by sites like [assembla](http://code.assembla.com/we20site/subversion/nodes/We20PinaxEd) looks promising; how can I set up something similar on my personal server?

I'm also open to suggestions and other methods of presentation such as a [directory listing](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/), but the web interface looks superior. The reason I prefer to host everything myself is because

- I don't want to pay in case Assembla changes their policy. They have in the past.
- The flexibility to try different things

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). It's [SVN browser](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser) looks like the thing you want.

Comment: providing a potential employer access to your SVN revision history will also give them insight into your development practices, not just your finished code.  This could be a double-edged sword, but if you're good, it could work very much in your favor.

Comment: You can have multiple SVN repositories and only making the one public with dedicated code fragments. Installing trac only for SVN browsing is perhaps a little overkill.

Comment: Trac is lightweight and very easy to install, so it doesn't matter that it's "overkill".

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/browse) or [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser)

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple SVN web browser. You check you code into a subversion repository and install one of the browser, perhaps this one http://www.subversionary.org/projects/web/svn-browser

Answer (score 1):

You could use the open source app [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org). The default looks are a bit outdated, but the css can be easily modified.